# Find nul(D), def(D)

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-topology

consider the differential operator $D=x+d/dx$ on R. Show that D defines a linear map $D: S(R)\rightarrow S(R)$. Find nul(D), def(D).

actually I dont understand how to calculate nul and def of a function exactly

Comment: Please give a definition for $nul(D)$ and $def(D)$.  I'd guess $nul(D)$ has something to do with the nullspace of $D$,  but these notations are a little nonstandard.

Comment: Also, what is $S(R)$?

Comment: in fact, i dont know excatly def mean, I think it is dim(D)